# Clear all the activities in backstack and restart main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have a scenario where I need to restart my application , when user clicks a button in main activity . 
**AppFlow: 
**
ActivityA   ->  ActivityB -> ActivityC

User presses back button in ActivityC and then in ActivityB and reaches to ActivityA.
In ActivityA when user clicks a button, app is closed by clearing the backstack and try to restart the ActivityA by finishing it. What is happening when app is exited from ActivityA, the ActivityB appears for a second and then app exits. My requirement is none of the Activities in backstack should appear when finishing ActivityA. 
 I used the below logic:

```
 Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.D(LOG_TAG , "finishAndRestartApp() -> creating pending intent");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
        Log.D(LOG_TAG ,start finishing mainActivity AND RESTART IT");
        finish();
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you mean when you click a button at Activity A -> go Activity B for a second and exit app?

Comment: No, when clicked on Button in ActivityA , App exits displaying ActivityB for few seconds . I don't want to see any other activities when I try to exit app in ActivityA

Answer (score 0):

Use `finishAffinity()` instead of `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);

intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

startActivity(intent);
```